# How to solve this special second-order non-linear ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm in trouble with solving the following differential equation:

$0=y\cdot y''-y^2-2(y')^2$

I would be thankful for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\textbf{hint}$

$$
y'' = y'\dfrac{d}{dy}y' = \frac{1}{2}\dfrac{d}{dy}y'^2
$$
And then set $y'^2=p$ you get a first order ode which you can solve for $p$ and if "God" has been nice you can solve for $y$.

$
\textbf{edit}
$

"god" was nice.

$$
y'^2 = C_1y^4 -y^2 \implies y' = \pm y\sqrt{C_1y^2-1}
$$
the integral can be written as $u^2 = C_1y^2-1$
$$
\int \frac{du}{u^2+1} 
$$
thus
$$
y(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{C_1}}\sec\left(x+C_2\right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

writing the differential equation as $y^{\prime \prime} = \dfrac{y^2 + 2{y^\prime}^2}{y}$. define a new variable $z = y^\prime$ writing the second order equation as two first order equations 
$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = z, \dfrac{dz}{dx} = \dfrac{y^2 + 2z^2}{y}$ combining the two we get $$\dfrac{dy}{dz }= \dfrac{zy}{y^2 + 2{z}^2}$$

now, we define $y$ and $z$ in terms of a parameter $t$ by the following differential equations $$\frac{dy}{dt} = y, \frac{dz}{dt} = \dfrac{y^2 + 2z^2}{z} $$

solving  the first equation, we get  $$y = Ae^t \tag 1$$ substittuing this in the second equation gives $$\dfrac{dz}{dt} = 2z + A^2 e^{2t}\dfrac{1}{z}$$ which can be rewritten as $$ (ze^{-2t}) d (ze^{-2t}) = A^2e^{-2t}dt  $$

on integrating the last equation , we get $$ z = \pm e^t\sqrt{Be^{2t} - A^2} \tag 2 $$

eliminating $t$ from $(1)$ and $(2)$ gives us a first order differential equation  $$z = \dfrac{dy}{dx} = \pm\dfrac{y\sqrt{By^2 - A^4}}{A^2}$$ which can be separated and integrated as $$ A^2 \int \dfrac{dy}{y\sqrt{By^2 - A^4}} = \pm(x+ C)$$.

p.s.: i dont know why i am getting a third constant. i will have to think some more about it.

p.s. 2: i took the long road. i see that chinny84 has a better answer.